# Explaining the bending problem of motorcycle in inertial system

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

How Do Motorcycles Lean So Far Without Tipping Over?

I know how to explain it with  in the accelerating frame, the centrifugal force  torque balanced with the torque of gravity. But I am wondering how can we understand it with inertial frame that the Motorcycles will not tipping over。

My guess: Usual Angular momentum theorem cannot use for this without consider centrifugal force  because it is Non inertial, so we can only see it as many mass point, we know from newton's second law, how every mass point moving, then we know it wont tipping over.

Is there a  way to explain it in inertial frame with torque?

Comment: Centrifugal force is just fictitious force. And which exists there that is centripetal force not centrifugal.

Comment: Yes, Centrifugal force is just fictitious force, But we use it to explain the balance of the motorcycles, so I also want to know how to explain it without centrifugal force.